# C++ Function arguments validation (pointer vs. reference arguments)

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When pass-by-pointer is preferred to pass-by-reference in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550377/when-pass-by-pointer-is-preferred-to-pass-by-reference-in-c)

Hello everyone,

What do you consider a better programming practice: passing objects as pointers or references to functions.
What do you do for input validation?

Thanks.

Comment: What are "address arguments" if not pointers?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550377/when-pass-by-pointer-is-preferred-to-pass-by-reference-in-c/2550489#2550489

Comment: Also, I think by "address arguments" you mean "references"?

Comment: yes, references. Sorry, long day :)

Answer (score 4):

It is better C++ style to use  a reference. One advantage to this, as  I believe you were implying, is that when passing by reference, you no longer need to verify that it is non-null, since references cannot be null. Also, I should add that if you are not modifying the parameter, then you should pass by constant reference. (For primitives or small non-polymorphic objects, you can also pass by value if you aren't modifying it).

Answer (score 2):

Probably go with references, because they're cleaner. With pointers, you have a very awkward syntax.

As for validation, I would just do an ASSERT.

Comment: Do you mean debug assertions or something like boost static assertions?