# In what situations is using 'const T*' preferable to 'const T&' for input parameters?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

In Google c++ code style, they have said there are some instances where using `const T*` is preferable to `const T&` for input parameters.

1. You want to pass in a null pointer
2. The function saves a pointer or reference to the input.

I don't understand the second one. Could you give me some examples? Thanks.

Comment: Did the style document not go into more detail?

Comment: Sorry, but the Google Style Guide is infamous for being against idiomatic C++.  Probably you shouldn't be following it unless you are forced to.

Comment: Hi. In addition to what @L.F. has said, please see: [difference between a pointer and reference parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/620604/3258851), [Pointers vs. References in C++ function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17900022/3258851), [Pass by reference vs pass by pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5893873/3258851) and [When to pass by reference and when to pass by pointer in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3613065/3258851), and duplicated/related questions.

Comment: @L.F. Sorry，I have updated the question,Please take another look.

Comment: @Marc.2377  I have updated the question. PTAL

Comment: @JaMit   I have added the detail.PTAL

Comment: @liangsun The second point looks like a (subjective) convention. If you use that convention and a function takes a pointer that cannot be null, then you can deduce that a copy of the pointer will be kept. At that point you should check the documentation to see how long the pointer will be kept. There are other ways to achieve the same goal (such as checking the documentation before using the function), so I would still go with the question being primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

> there are some instances where using const T* is preferable to const T& for input parameters
>
> 2.The function saves a pointer or reference to the input. I don't understand the second one. Could you give me some examples

Example:

```
int* ptr;
void foo(int& ref)
{
    ptr = &ref; // function saves a pointer or reference to the input
                // therefore using ref input is not preferable
                // according to the guideline
}
```