# why this function does not change pointers value?

Tags: c++, pointers

The output prints the same value - 8;
I am not able to get why *p = 15 does not modify the the pointers value?

```
void foo(int *p) {
    int q = 19;
    p = &q;
    *p = 15;
}
int main() {
    int x = 8;
    int *y = &x;

    foo(y);
    cout << x << " " << *y << endl;

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Why it should ?

Comment: Get rid of `p = &q;` and it will do what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842416/function-does-not-change-passed-pointer-c

Comment: why a local variable q in function foo? it does nothing.

Comment: @JohnZ.Li: It's a rebind target. It's meant to demonstrate that `p` and `y` are not the same pointer, because `p = &q` did not affect `y`.

Comment: Thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

You have changed the adress of  q when execute the follow instruction in the function

```
p = &q
```

Answer (score 0):

It *does* modify the value pointed-to, but when it does so the pointer is pointing to the variable `q` in `foo`, not the variable `x` in `main` (which remains unchanged).

The other part of the puzzle is that, at that time, the pointer in question was a *copy* of the original pointer. There is no relationship between the `p` in `foo`, and the `y` in `main`, other than `p` begins life initialised with `y`'s value.

Comment: I suggest running through the steps of your program on paper and track the value of everything as you go. You will soon find out where you went wrong in your mind (and, if not, then you have something more concrete to ask us). This is called "debugging".