# FILE* initialisation in different function c++

Tags: c++, function, file, pointers, initialization

I need to initialise FILE *fi in different function. This example code shows the problem.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void init(FILE* fi) 
{ 
    fi=fopen("in.txt", "r");    
    if(fi==NULL) 
    {       
        cout<<"Got NULL\n";     
    } 
}

int main()  
{   
    FILE* fi;   
    init(fi);   
    if(fi==NULL)    
    {       
        cout<<"NULL\n";         
        return 0;   
    }   
    return 0;  
}
```

The program outputs NULL (not "Got NULL"), and I don't have a clue how to make it work...

---

It is important that I have fi passed as a pointer, not getting it as a return value.

Comment: In.txt is in same directiory as your executable file?

Comment: yes, no problems with files, pointer fi is equal to NULL in main, but not in init

Comment: `fi` is effectively  a local variable of the `init` function. You need to pass the pointer by reference.

Comment: Given this is tagged C++, please read up in "pass by reference" and how parameters are passed in C++. Because --obviously-- the value of (the pointer) `fi` is passed by value into `init()` here and thus any changes to that value inside of `ìnit()` become void outside of `init()`.

Comment: Likely duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842416/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't manipulate arguments unless that's the specific intent of the code. It's better to simply *return* things:

```
FILE* init()
{ 
    return fopen("in.txt", "r");
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
FILE* fi = init();
```

Note that since you're using C++ you should avoid using C anachronisms like `FILE` and instead use C++ file streams.

If you need to handle multiple return values:

```
std::tuple<FILE*, FILE*> init() {
  return std::make_tuple(
    fopen("in.txt", "r"),
    fopen("out.txt", "w")
  );
}
```

This is just a step towards making it proper C++ code by encapsulating all of this inside a proper `class` definition and then you can manipulate properties directly:

```
class FileWrapper {
public:
  FileWrapper();
  ~FileWrapper();
  void init();

protected:
  FILE *fi;
  FILE *fo;
}

void FileWrapper::init() {
  fi = fopen("in.txt", "r");
  fo = fopen("out.txt", "w");
}
```

In that case you don't even need return values. You'll also be able to automatically clean up those filehandles when that wrapper class gets deallocated if you write a proper destructor.

Comment: It is important that I have fi passed as a pointer, not getting it as a return value.

Comment: Why is that important? You'll need to clarify because in your code it's not the case. In old-school C you'd use a pointer-pointer occasionally for such things, but in C++ there's a strong philosophy built up around returning objects that are cheap to copy.

Comment: My code is just an example, I'm trying to have pointers pointing to stdin and stdout of a child process, thats two of them, so its easier to pass them as pointers

Comment: You might think it's easier, but there's usually a better way than manipulating arguments. Don't pass in mutable arguments, instead save  return values. For example, you can return a simple `tuple` or `struct` which contains the values.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it.

Replase

```
void init(FILE* fi)
```

with

```
void init(FILE*&fi)
```

Comment: This is a "fix" but it's only making a mess of things.