# Why is a double pointer needed to make changes to head but not elsewhere in a linklist

Tags: c++

```
void insertAtTop(node** head, int value){
    node* temp=new node();
    temp->data=value;
    temp->next=*head;
    *head=temp;
}

void insertAtLast(node*head, int value){
    while(head->next!=NULL){
        head=head->next;
    }
    node*temp=new node();
    temp->data=value;
    temp->next=NULL;
    head->next=temp;
}
```

I can't understand why you need to use a pointer to pointer to make changes to the head but if you want to add an element elsewhere you can do it simply by sending `node* head` instead of `node** head`. Like for `insertatLast` `node*head` as argument works but if I did the same for `insertAtTop` it wouldn't.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842416/function-does-not-change-passed-pointer-c

Comment: In `c++` you should use `void insertAtTop(node* & head, int value){` instead.

Comment: ***I can't understand why you need to use a pointer to pointer to make changes to the head but if you want to add an element elsewhere you can do it simply by sending `node*` head instead of `node**` head.*** With `node*` you are passing the pointer by value. When you pass a value it is a copy. Changing the copy has no effect on the calling function.

Comment: Look at the _calling_ code. You passed in a head pointer. What should it be after you inserted a new node at the front? Is that the same if you insert a new node after the head?

Comment: NB. This is one reason why using a sentinel node (with next=head) can be nice: it makes most operations including this more regular, with fewer special corner cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve both `insertAtTop` and `insertAtLast` by using both `pass by reference` and `pass by value`. I suggest you to read [difference between pass by reference and pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value). You can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c).

I assume `head` is declared as `node* head;`

**Pass by reference:**

```
void insertAtTop(node** head, int value){
    node* temp=new node();
    temp->data=value;
    temp->next=*head;
    *head=temp;
}
```

Call: `insertAtTop(&head, value);`

```
void insertAtLast(node** head, int value){
    node* h = *head;
    while(h->next!=NULL){
        h = h->next;
    }
    node* new_node=new node();
    new_node->data=value;
    new_node->next=NULL;
    h->next=new_node;
}
```

Call: `insertAtLast(&head, value);`

**Pass by value:**

```
node* insertAtTop(node* head, int value){
    node* temp=new node();
    temp->data=value;
    temp->next= head;
    head = temp;
    return head;
}
```

Call: `head = insertAtTop(head, value);`

```
node* insertAtLast(node* head, int value){
    node* original_head = head;
    while(head->next!=NULL){
        head=head->next;
    }
    node*temp=new node();
    temp->data=value;
    temp->next=NULL;
    head->next=temp;
    return original_head;
}
```

Call: `head = insertAtLast(head, value);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a double pointer. See the code below:

```
node* front(int n, node* head)
{
    node *tmp = new node;
    tmp -> data = n;
    tmp -> next = head;
    head = tmp;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Good try Ram. But changes made to `head` inside `front()` will only persist in the `front()`. They won't be persisted once you return from the `front()`.

Comment: oh yes, my bad!.should return the head?

Comment: Yes. Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With a double pointer, you’re passing a pointer to a pointer.  When you have a single pointer, dereferencing it gives you the value of the variable.  With a double pointer, dereferencing gives you the address of the variable in memory. When you’re adding the node to the front of the list, you’re taking the node you’ve already created for the head node and passing in the address of the pointer to it.  And the reason you have to do this for adding to the head of the linked list specifically is that you already have a reference somewhere in memory to the head of the list since a linked list struct is defined as having a head node originally pointing at null and subsequent additions to the front of the list are going to change where to look for the start of that linked list.

Answer (score 0):

There is a double pointer in both. Look at these two analogous lines from the two functions:

```
*head=temp;  // from insertAtTop

head->next=temp; // from insertAtLast
```

Note that `head->next = temp` can be equivalently written as `(*head).next = temp`.

There is a "double pointer" there: `head` is a pointer to a structure, and that structure contains a pointer `next`. Basically these two pictures:

Diagram for `*head = temp`:

```
head --> [ *--]---> old_head
            ^
            `-- temp is stored here, replacing the old_head
```

Diagram for `head->next = temp`, or `(*head).next = temp`. For the sake of example, the node structure is represented as three memory cells, the third of which is the `next` field. The exact memory details depend on your compiler and how you defined the structure!

```
head  --> [    ]
          [    ] 
          [ *--]--> old_next
             ^
             `-- temp is stored here, replacing old_next
```

Basically, the only difference is that you we have a structure instead of a just a single pointer object.

In both cases, a pointer is being updated to refer to the newly inserted node. In the `insertAtTop` case, we have to replace that very pointer which represents the list itself. We are representing a list object as a pointer to the first node. If the list is changed so that it has a different first node, that pointer has to change. When inserting elsewhere in the list, we must update the previous node's `next` pointer to point to the new node, so we assign to `(*head).next`.

We could rewrite `insertAtLast` to use `insertAtTop` as a subroutine:

```
node* insertAtLast(node* head, int value){
    /* find the insertion point */
    node* original_head = head;
    while(head->next!=NULL){
        head=head->next;
    }
    /* now treat that as the head */
    (void) insertAtTop(&head->next, value);
    return original_head;
}
```

If you trace what happens in the call to `insertAtHead`, you will find that it does exactly the same thing as the code which we replaced. We took out this code:

```
    node* new_node=new node();
    new_node->data=value;
    new_node->next=NULL;
    h->next=new_node;
```

But that's almost the same as the body of `insertAtHead` which is this:

```
   node* temp=new node();
   temp->data=value;
   temp->next=*head;
   *head=temp;
```

We pass the value of the expression `&h->next` as the `head` parameter. So `temp->next = *head` is really `temp->next = *&h->next` where the `*&` cancel out, leaving `temp->next = h->next`.  But we know that `h->next` is `NULL`: our `while` loop has ensured that. So this is `temp->next = NULL`, effectively.
And of course `*head = temp` is the  same as `*(&h->next) = temp`, which is `h->next = temp`.